# Reputation league on page footer

Tags: feature-request, reputation, footer

Currently, there are many links on page footer, but one is missing : the reputation league !

Indeed, I think it's a part of the StackOverflow global experience, and as such, it should be visible to users.

And as far as I understand StackOverflow page logic, I guess this link should appear with all other ones : in page footer of all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is visible to users on the user page.  https://stackoverflow.com/users

Answer (score 0):

There is a link to Stack Exchange on the **top** of every page.  That will take you to StackExchange.com, and from there you can see the reputation leagues.